# GWT, programmatically get the same effect of a hyperlink

Tags: gwt, redirect, hyperlink

So some background, I am working in GWT, using MVP and activities and places. So I have all my stuff working with hyperlinks, and places are changing. I am also using a PlaceController.gotTo(Place).

Now what I want to do is be able to send the person to another place but programatically. Right now with the setup GWT manages the converting of the url into a place, and then fires the activities from that, but what I would like, is to either convert a url to a place, using the same way gwt does it or change the url, and fire a history changed type of effect onto the site.

What I don't need is an anchor to reload my whole site, I just want to feed a string into something and get the whole place change situation moving.

I want the effect of a hyperlink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're trying to do, but `PlaceHistoryMapper` is the only *tool* that GWT uses: feed a String to `getPlace` and it gives your the corresponding place. Alternately, you could use `History.newItem` (note that contrary to `PlaceController#goTo`, if the user cancels the `PlaceChangeRequestEvent`, the URL would have already changed).